# Newbie Python Script - read()

Tags: python, file

I am trying to learn more about python and wrote a simple script but I can't get the read() function to work.  What am I missing?  The error message I am getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex16demo.py", line 28, in 
    print glist.read()
IOError: File not open for reading

I file should be open and assigned to the glist variable.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We are creating a new grocery list!"

print "Opening %r..." % filename
glist = open(filename, 'w')

print "Deleting previous content from %r......" % filename
glist.truncate()

print "Add your items now:"
item1 = raw_input("item 1:")
item2 = raw_input("item 2:")
item3 = raw_input("item 3:")

print "Adding your items to the list...."
glist.write(item1)
glist.write("\n")
glist.write(item2)
glist.write("\n")
glist.write(item3)
glist.write("\n")

print "Here are the items in your grocery list:"

print glist.read()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'w' in `glist = open(filename, 'w')` means you're opening the file in 'write' mode. You'll need to `close()` it and re-open it in 'read' mode (`open(filename, 'r')`) to print out the contents.

Comment: I think you meant `open(filename, 'r')` for the read-mode example.

Answer (score 4):

The file was opened for writing (see `open(filename, 'w')`).

Close the file, open it for reading and then call `read()`:

```
glist.close()

glist = open(filename, 'r')
print glist.read()
```

Or, you can open file in `r+` mode to read and write without reopening (thanks to @sberry's comment).

Also, consider using `with` context manager instead of manually closing the opened file:

```
with open(filename, 'r+'):

    print "Deleting previous content from %r......" % filename
    glist.truncate()

    ...

    print glist.read()
```

Also see:

- [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on `open()` modes
- [python open built-in function: difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)

Comment: Thanks! Make sense.  I tried the first option but I will look at the 'r+' or 'w+' options.